# make text field required only if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: laravel-5

Basically I want textfield to be required only if checkbox is unchecked

I have read documentation from https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation but no option is working till now.

Will requiredif is help in this case? if yes, how I will pass if checkbox is checked or unchecked?

I have tried with requiredif and requiredunless but now getting

is this possible through laravel default validation? any suggestions?

Following is my code

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'exp_company' => 'required',
            'exp_designation' => 'required',
            'exp_location' => 'required',
            'start_date' => 'required',
            'end_date'   => 'requiredif:current_company,0'
         ]);
```

here current_company is checkbox field name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `required_without`

```
'end_date'   => 'required_without:current_company'
```